# How to get the function of a change in Python?

Tags: python, git

I am working on a Python script that aims to output the functions in which changes since the last Git commit occurred. For example, if I have the following code already in the most updated Git repo:

```
def testFunction():
   print('hello')
```

And I made the following change that has not yet been pushed to Git:

```
def testFunction():
   print('bye')
```

My script should output the function "testFunction."

Is there any existing Python libraries or modules that can accomplish something like this? If not, what approach can I use to accomplish this?

One approach I was thinking is to first get the line number of the change. For example, if print('hello') is on line 2 and I changed it to print('bye'), then my script should be able to detect the change occurred on line 2. It seems like 'git diff' is able to do something like this since it provides a range of line numbers, but I am not sure if it can provide the exact line number. Then once I have the line number where the change occurred, I may be able to use a module called inspect (docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) to get me a list of functions and the line numbers of functions. If the line number of the change is between a certain range of line numbers, then that change is in that function.

Comment: Why are you reinventing `git diff`?

Comment: This is part of a larger automation project that I am working on and part of the automation process relies on detecting the correct functions where changes occurred. git diff does not tell me which function the change occurred in. I guess as a human, it is easy to run git diff, see where the changes are, and go through the entire file to find the function. But right now, I am working with a lot of files and a lot of changes and running git diff and identifying the functions manually takes a lot of time, hence the automation.

Comment: If you are interested in my 2 cents, I believe it would be much easier to execute `git diff` programmatically and parse its output (you will possibly need to use some flags, read its docs to see which ones will alter the output to be easier to work with) than comming up with your own tool from scratch

Comment: Thank you! That sounds helpful, I will give that a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to figure out how to do this from scratch. `git diff` shows the changes in "hunks". Each hunk starts with a line, called the "hunk header" in diff jargon, which looks like:

`@@ -38,4 +38,4 @@ def some_func():`

Basically the part after the second `@@` is what you are looking for. The caveat here is that the default hunk header detection patterns (defined in [this file](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6d2f208c3dd39493f4d45ea67c55a1b7fe06626a/userdiff.c)) will use the class name as the hunk header if the changes are on some class function as opposed to a top level function. So if that's not what you want, you'll need to customize the hunk header patterns, see https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes,  "Defining a custom hunk-header".

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am still confused on what exactly I need to do to customize the hunk header patterns though. Is it even possible to change it to display the function? I followed the "defining a custom hunk-header" instructions by adding "*.tex diff=tex" in .gitattributes and adding the section with "xfuncname" in my .gitconfig file but when I ran git diff I didn't notice any differences. It seems like I need to edit the section after xfuncname in quotes but I am not exactly sure of the syntax.

Comment: It's essentially a list of regex patterns. So you need to make sure the patterns are correct in your custom header definition. See the default patterns for samples here https://github.com/git/git/blob/6d2f208c3dd39493f4d45ea67c55a1b7fe06626a/userdiff.c

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This solution works really unreliably in `2.39.3`. In my case, it was referencing a class that was just above and it missed two other classes changed below. I would not recommend it.